# How to do cascade delete efficiently in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've been looking for a performant way to do cascade deletes, but haven't been able to. Seems like I have to use `.Include()` to load any dependencies before passing my `IQueryable` to `RemoveRange()`, which takes a long time as it loads up all these entries in memory first.

Is there a way to just directly issue a SQL command using EF to delete the entities in question along with any dependencies?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx)?

Comment: If the performances are your main concerne, you should run away from EF.

Comment: yes fredrik I did look at that. My problem is not setting it up, but actually executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you use UnitOfWork you can execute sql with`ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`

```
 public async Task<int> ExecuteCommandAsync(string sqlCommand, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return await this.DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sqlCommand, parameters);
        }
```

Or if you use context directly

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "Delete from MyTable where Id=@id";
    var name = new SqlParameter(@id", 1);


    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[example](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql)

Using Fluent API to configure entities to turn off cascade delete using the `WillCascadeOnDelete()`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Riz I believe you need to call SaveChanges

Comment: i tried this, but doesn't seem to work. The records still stay there.

Comment: this not work?? `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from xxx where xx_id=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", id)`

Comment: sorry, it's giving an exception about cascade deletes. maybe i don't have it setup properly

Comment: so probably you have to configure or use Fluent API to configure entities to turn off cascade delete using the `WillCascadeOnDelete()`  `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }`

Comment: thanks, taht's exactly what I did yesterday before I had to leave. I will let you know the results.

Comment: it worked, but I am using caching (https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache), and so the items still stay in the cache. I'm not sure of a good solution to invalidate the relevant cached items.

Comment: @Riz  To "clear the cache" is to just Dispose the context instance and create another one.
You most certainly should NOT create a DbContext instance and just hold onto it for the lifetime of your application.

Comment: the dbContext is disposed of with each request. The issue is that I am using the in-memory cache as I linked above for caching items and they need to be invalidated. I've marked your response as answer, and posted another question relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to delete multiple entities:

- Delete everything manually. This way you have to load them in memory first which you don't want.
- Configure [cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) rules so that your database will delete the dependencies for you.
- You can use third party extensions like [this one](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus#batch-delete) to delete manually what you want, but there is no roundtrip to the database necessary and nothing needs to be loaded in the context before.

Comment: thanks marc, but as i understand it, EF 6 by default sets up relationships to cascade on delete. My issue is that when I just use RemoveRange on the main query, none of the dependencies are affected ( I get an error) simply because not all the dependencies are loaded in the entity tracker. This error goes away if I do load them all, but it's horribly inefficient.